# Short one: invalid conversion from char to const char*

Tags: c++, char, strcat

code:

```
void setup(){
 Serial.begin(19200);
 static char value [20] = "20:17:12";
 setSimTime(value);
}

void setSimTime(char* incoming){
  char dateTime[20];
  strcat(dateTime, "20");
  strcat(dateTime, incoming[0-1]);
  Serial.println(dateTime);
}
```

What is the right way to do this? 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: `incoming[0-1]` What do you think this does? You are trying to access index `-1` in an array, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @BoBTFish I was trying to acces 0 to 1

Comment: Which line you get the error in the title?

Comment: @sdd, this is no Python, where similar tricks work, you have to copy this entire chunk and feed it to the function. Or put a null-terminator at `incoming[2]`, but this'll replace the original value at that index, if any.

Comment: What output do you expect? (with `Serial.println(dateTime)`?)

Comment: @em2er I expect "2020"

Comment: `char dateTime[20]` contains garbage not terminated with `'\0'` because it uninitialized. So `strcat(dateTime, "20");` will concatenate a garbage with "20". Define`char dateTime[20]={0};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strcat(dateTime, incoming[0-1]);`, where `incoming[0-1]` is the same as `incoming[-1]` causes undefined behavior. In fact `incoming[-1]` is the single character located at array index `-1`, this is the cause of the error, the compiler cannot convert a single character (`char`) into an char pointer (`char*`).

Instead use:

```
strncat(dateTime, incoming, 2);
```

note the `n` in `strncat`. This will concatenate at most two characters from `incoming` to `dateTime`, and put a terminating null-character.

**Extension**

You can extend this to:

```
strncat(dateTime, incoming + n, l);
```

Where `n` is the starting index, i.e., zero before, and `l` is the max length to copy.

**Example**

So if you what to concatenate the characters with indexes 3 and 4 do:

```
strncat(dateTime, incoming + 3, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you, and how if I want to access 3 to 4?

Comment: Thank you. I am using the dateTime so set up the RTC clock:
clock.setDateTime(dateTime); but this gives the error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'uint32_t. Any chance you know why?

Comment: clock.setDateTime does not accept a string (`char*`). You could convert the string to a UNIX timestamp using `timegm`.

Answer (score 1):

The exact error message comes from the fact that `incoming[0-1]` is of type `char`, but `strcat` expects a `const char*` as second parameter, which is a pointer to a `char`.

The additional `const` is not a problem here, because non-const values can always be converted to const values.

See other answers/comments on the invalidity of `incoming[0-1]`.